# Почему комментарии добавляются только после перезапуска сервера django?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, django-admin

Через админ панель добавляются без проблем, а через input только при перезагрузке сервера.
Что я делаю не так?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Source
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone

source_list = Source.objects.order_by('-source_date')[:22]

def index(request):
    return render(request,'source/AllCode.html', {'source_list': 
source_list})

def showcode(request, source_id):
    try:
        s = Source.objects.get( id = source_id )
    except:
        HttpResponseRedirect('/source')
    return render(request, 'source/Code.html', {'source': s})

def addcode(request):
    try:
        newsource = Source( source_title = request.POST['title'], 
source_language = request.POST['language'],\
        source_code = request.POST['code'], source_date = timezone.now())   
        newsource.save()

         return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('source:showcode', args = 
(newsource.id, )) )

    except:
        return render(request, 'source/save.html')
```

Comment: Обращаетесь к БД в top-level выражении.

Comment: Потому что вы читаете комментарии из базы данных только в момент перезапуска и больше никогда их не перечитываете.

Comment: andreymal, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def index(request):
    source_list = Source.objects.order_by('-source_date')[:22]
    return render(request,'source/AllCode.html', {'source_list': 
source_list})
```